# How to Cascading DropDownList using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have implemented Cascading (Dependent) DropDownList using ASP.Net MVC. But the redirect to index.cshtml not working because all the DropDownList on the form are empty except the first DropDownList that populates correctly. How to fill the state dropdownlist based on the data of the country dropdownlist?

Controller

```
public ActionResult page()
        {
            string con = Properties.Settings.Default.db;
            MySqlConnection con_main = new MySqlConnection(con);

            con_main.Open();
            MySqlCommand listK = new MySqlCommand("", con_main);
            var listcountry = new List<dropdownc>();
            listc.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM master_country";
            MySqlDataReader rc = listc.ExecuteReader();
            while (rc.Read())
            {
                listcountry.Add(new dropdownc
                {
                    id = rc[0].ToString(),
                    name = rc[1].ToString()
                });

            }
            ViewBag.country = new SelectList(listcountry, "id", "name");

            con_main.Close();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getstate(string Id)
        {
            string con = Properties.Settings.Default.db;
            MySqlConnection con_main = new MySqlConnection(con);
            MySqlCommand lists = new MySqlCommand("", con_main);
            var liststate = new List<dropdowns>();
            con_main.Open();
            listsc.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM master_state WHERE id_country = '" + Id + "' ";
            MySqlDataReader rs = listsc.ExecuteReader();
            while (rs.Read())
            {
                liststate.Add(new dropdowns
                {
                    id = rs[0].ToString(),
                    name = rs[1].ToString()
                });

            }
           
            con_main.Close();
            return Json(liststate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View

```
 <div id="dropDownListdiv">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CascadingDropDownList", FormMethod.Post))
     {
          @Html.DropDownList("country", "Select Country")
          @Html.DropDownList("state", new SelectList(" "), "Select State")
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
</div>
```

JavaScript Code on View

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#country").change(function () {
            $.get("~/pageControl/getstate", { Id: $("#country").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#state").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#state").append("<option value='" + row.id + "'>" + row.name + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+cascading+dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ajax to do something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#country").change(function () {
            BindStatesForDropDown();
        });
    });
    
    function BindStatesForDropDown() {

        var objParam = new Object();
        objParam.Id = $("#country").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/pageControl/getstate",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(objParam),
            success: function (res) {
                $("#state").empty();
                if (res.length > 0) {
                    $.each(res, function (key, data) {
                        $("#state").append($("<option></option>").val(data.id).html(data.name));
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (res) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```